# why does the Tkinter window is blank on execution?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
if v==1:                   #some how v becomes equal to 1#
       c_object=abcd()
class abcd():                  #class abcd created#
       root=Tk()
```

> The code seems to run succesfully until here but gives blank window after this

```
       def __init__(self):
          label_1=i1=Label(root,text="?")
          label_1.pack(anchor=W)
          self.c=Entry(root)
          self.c.pack(anchor=E)
       def execution(self):
         ????
       root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried running your code and got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. I replaced `????` with `pass` and got `NameError: name 'v' is not defined`. I added `v = 1` and got `NameError: name 'abcd' is not defined`. I moved the class definition above the conditional and got `NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined`. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in your `__init__` function ever executes, because `root.mainloop` executes first, when the class definition is being evaluated, and it never returns until you close the window.

One possible solution is to move `root = Tk()` and `root.mainloop()` inside the function.

```
class abcd():                  #class abcd created#
    def __init__(self):
        root=Tk()
        label_1=i1=Label(root,text="?")
        label_1.pack(anchor=W)
        self.c=Entry(root)
        self.c.pack(anchor=E)
        root.mainloop()
```

However, it's hard to say whether this is the best solution, without knowing what the rest of your code looks like.

Comment: thank u kevin , i am new to stackexchange and will keep in mind ur advise